# Want to share image via google+ api

Tags: image, api, share, google-plus

This is my code

```
<button
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="http://www.pubandbar-network.co.uk/nightlife_pubs-bars.html" 
  data-clientid="102180630313-ef89c6gjgahgitf0s9qknhrl5mo351ga.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
  data-calltoactionurl="http://www.pubandbar-network.co.uk/nightlife_pubs-bars.html"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">  Share 
</button>
```

I want to share image with this. Please help me how can I share image via google+ API.
My second question is :
Is there any way in php to share on google+ automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The images that appear in shares are calculated by Google based on the schema data on your page. As an example, you can use the [snippet configuration tool](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) to configure the image and description for your share. When you set the content-url to point to the page with schema, Google will use that schema microdata to set the image and so forth.

You cannot share programmatically to Google+ except with [Google+ App Activities](https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities).